# Assets are hiding under the map for Terrain with Labels with ArcGIS Runtime maps Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, esri, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

Assets are hiding under the map for Terrain with Labels basemap.It is not happening with other basemaptypes like Streetvector. ArcGIS Runtime 100.13.0 and Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2337 used.please help to solve the issue. [image]

```
myMap.Basemap = Basemap.CreateTerrainWithLabelsVector();
myMap.OperationalLayers.Add(publicLayer);
featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureLayer);
await _featureLayer.LoadAsync();
myMap.OperationalLayers.Add(_featureLayer);
MyMapView.Map = myMap;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. Turns out there is a bug in the Runtime SDK to do with this basemap when created from the Basemap static factory method which we'll address in the next release.

**UPDATE**: The [100.14.1 patch that was released today](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-runtime-sdks-blog/arcgis-runtime-sdk-100-14-1-now-available/ba-p/1183295) should address this.

You could adopt the [Basemap Styles Enum](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.BasemapStyle.html) and [constructor](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.Basemap.-ctor.html#Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Mapping_Basemap__ctor_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Mapping_BasemapStyle_), which uses metered basemaps and [requires an API Key](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.Basemap.ApiKey.html#Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Mapping_Basemap_ApiKey) or other authentication, or you could [create the basemap from a Portal Item](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/api-reference/api/netwin/Esri.ArcGISRuntime/Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.Basemap.-ctor.html#Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Mapping_Basemap__ctor_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Portal_Item_) ([this is the Portal Item](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a52ab98763904006aa382d90e906fdd5) for the Terrain with Labels web map).